# removing numbers that immediately precede words

Tags: python, regex

Trying to get rid of the numbers in the below sentence. Can anyone help?
Thanks

```
x="genes1,2,4,5... activation5–10... modifications11–14... previously15."
```

My attempt:

```
x=re.sub(r'([a-z]),([1-100])', r'\1\2', x)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
 "genes... activation... modifications... previously".
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: You want to remove just number or also `-`, `,`?

Comment: sorry edited appropriately- yes i want to remove the hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for

```
[-\d,]+
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fG8CJN/1).

Which in `Python` would be:

```
import re

x="genes1,2,4,5... activation5–10... modifications11–14... previously15."
x = re.sub(r'[-\d,]+', '', x)
print(x)
```

*Note that you have another kind of dash in your original question here*.

Comment: Hi there thanks for that but I got the following error when I tried it on the full text:

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'.... but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details